# Debian/Jessie: Easiest way to connect to VPN (Ipsec)

Tags: debian, openvpn, vpn

what is the most recent, easiest way to connect to a `Ipsec VPN` from a Debian/Jessie host?

I read about `openvpn`, `opwenswan` and what not but I expected to find a pretty easy kind of standard way to connect to a VPN via Linux. Well I thought, because it is Linux, it should be dead simple because networking is what Linux is all about :) But what I found seems to be pretty complicated (PPT, iptables, routes, openswan, kernel ...).

Can you point me to some how to or help me in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For connecting to an IPsec VPN as a client, vpnc is quite easy to install and use. Our Linux users use it to connect to our PfSense IPsec VPNs.

For installing it:

```
sudo apt-get install vpnc
```

To configure it, for instance, an IPsec VPN with PSK+Xauth authentication:

```
sudo vi /etc/vpnc/default.conf

IPSec gateway your_DNS_or_IP_address_VPN_server
IPSec ID yourgroup
IPSec secret your_secret
IKE Authmode psk
Xauth username username
Xauth password password
```

To connect to the VPN:

```
sudo vpnc
```

To disconnect from the VPN:

```
sudo vpnc-disconnect
```

See: [man vpnc](https://linux.die.net/man/8/vpnc)

Comment: Do you know how to use vpnc *without* Xauth? - With preshared key only?

Comment: @mcantsin Please open a new question.